# Зачем добавлять в каждом наследнике интерфейсе те же самые методы

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс

Зачем добавлять в каждом наследнике интерфейсе те же самые методы?
Вот к примеру в Java, `List` интерфейс наследуется от `Collection` но объявлены те же самые методы что и в `Collection`, как будто я мог бы использовать интерфейс `List` исключая наследование от `Collection`.

Comment: Почему в конкретном примере такое сделали, я не знаю. Но по идее это не обязательно. Ты можешь создать интерфейс ListExt наследующий List, но не объявляющий ни единого метода. И при реализации этого интерфейса в классе, ты все равно будешь обязан реализовать все методы Листа

Comment: Я это понимаю, потому и задал вопрос, зачем так делать, если можно было не объявлять эти методы в интерфейсе, это не единственный пример, я такое часто встречал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Зачем добавлять в каждом наследнике интерфейсе те же самые методы

Если **кратко**, то для изменения javadoc методов.

Если **подробнее**, то:
Это не обязательно - все зависит от того, изменяется контракт метода или нет.
Контракт определяется сигнатурой метода и документацией к нему. В случае с `Collection` и его дочерними интерфейсами `List`, `Set` и т.д. контракт методов определяется в интерфейсе каждой из коллекций.
Например, по контракту метод `boolean add(E e)` для `Set` исключает дубликаты, а `List` - нет.

Аналогичный вопрос на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767794/interfaces-in-collections-framework)

Answer (score 1):

Я предполагаю, что это было сделано **для улучшения документации**: теперь у наследников **Collection** можно в документации указать дополнительные подробности над переопределенными методами. Рассмотрим на примере метода **iterator()**:

```
public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E> {
    ...
    /**
     * Returns an iterator over the elements in this collection.  There are no
     * guarantees concerning the order in which the elements are returned
     * (unless this collection is an instance of some class that provides a
     * guarantee).
     *
     * @return an <tt>Iterator</tt> over the elements in this collection
     */
    Iterator<E> iterator();
    ...
}  

public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {
    ...
    /**
     * Returns an iterator over the elements in this list in proper 
     sequence.
     *
     * @return an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence
     */
    Iterator<E> iterator();
    ...
}  

public interface Set<E> extends Collection<E> {
    ...
    /**
     * Returns an iterator over the elements in this set.  The elements are
     * returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some
     * class that provides a guarantee).
     *
     * @return an iterator over the elements in this set
     */
    Iterator<E> iterator();
    ...
}
```

Comment: А метод int size() что у Collection что у List все одинаково

Comment: Я думаю, что такие методы как int size(), которые не имеют особых различий в деталях, были переопределны ради того, чтобы придерживаться одного стиля. Возможно это было сделано для удобства, чтобы не приходилось идти в интерфейс предка , чтобы узнать все методы.